# Can't compile Qt Creator 3 using MSVC 2010

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to Compile Qt Creator 3.0.0 using Qt 5.2.0 and MSVC 2010 on Windows 7 64bit and I am getting this compile error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\inc\wdbgexts.h(34) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winapifamily.h': No such file or directory extensioncontext.cpp
```

What could be the reason? (Note that I have Windows SDK 8 installed...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/requirements-win.html and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html ?
Also given the space in your path. Have you searched for the include files? Are they on the system?

Comment: Well actually these pages are for Qt 4.8. On the other hand, what I read before attempting to compile was the README file shipped with Qt Creator. It contained a section called "Compiling Qt Creator" so I simply did what that section says, but now I scrolled down and noticed another section called "Compiling Qt and Qt Creator on Windows" which contains different information xD I'll do what it says in there and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Lawand - did you find a solution?  I don't see anything in the addition instructions that would provide 'winapifamily.h'